# How to make assignments in Constructor using initialisation list

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to make a constructor for my own `Vector` class, to which I pass the `length` of the vector to be made and a single default `value` to fill it.

How am I supposed to iterate through every item of the `array_` in order to asign them to `value` using an initialisation list as below?

This would have been easy to do, were I to use a constructor body. But I've read that using an initialisation list is better.

```
class Vector{
private:
int size_;
int* array_;

public:
Vector(int length, int value) : size_(length), array_(new int[length * 2]) { }

}
```

Comment: You can't. You have to use statements inside the constructor body for the element initialization, like `std::fill_n(array_n, size_ * 2, value);`

Comment: I'd make a static static helper function, `static int* make_array(int length, int value) {...}` and initialize `array_{make_array(length, value)}` in the initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use just initializer lists to get it done. Use `std::fill_n` like this,

```cpp
class Vector{
private:
int size_;
int* array_;

public:
Vector(int length, int value) : size_(length), array_(new int[length * 2]) 
{ 
    std::fill_n(array_, length, 0);
}

}
```

Note: Using `array_(new int[length * 2])` might not be the best way to allocate the buffer. For example, if the user wants to store just 100 integers, you actually allocate 200 entries worth of memory. This might be a good idea for performance but might not be for memory. Another thing is that your vector only supports integers. If you want to support other types as well, make it a templated class.